# division by zero error on dictionary python

Tags: python

```
def getSortedKeyList(dl):
    kl = list(dl.items())
    kl.sort()
    return kl

def tupleListToDict(a):
    b = {}
    for k, v in a:
        b[k] = b.get(k, [])+v
    return b

def main():
    gradeList = [('Zaphod', [33, 20]), ('Zaphod', [75, 48]), \
                 ('Slartibartfast', []), ('Trillian', [98, 88]), \
                 ('Trillian', [97, 77]), ('Slartibartfast', []), \
                 ('Marvin', [2000, 500]), ('Authur', [42, 20]), \
                 ('Authur', [64]), ('Trillian', [99]), \
                 ('Marvin', [450]), ('Marvin', [550]), \
                 ('Agrajag', []), ('Agrajag', []), ('Agrajag', [0]), \
                 ('Ford', [50]), ('Ford', [50]), ('Ford', [50])]

    print('\t', '\t', "Grade", '\t')
    print('\t', "Name", '\t', "Count", '\t', "Average")
    print("-----------------------------------------")

    dicList = tupleListToDict(gradeList)            
    dicList = getSortedKeyList(dicList)

    for k, v in dicList:
        print(k, len(v), '\t', sum(v)/len(v))
```

I'm trying to make a table from a dictionary. First of all, I converted the tuple to dictionary and sorted the dictionary by keys. Next, I'm trying to print out the (keys, num of keys, average). However, when I try to do sum(v)/len(v) for the average part, I get division by zero error. To avoid the error, I tried to return the empty value from the dictionary to 0, but I just do not know how to do so. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
def getSortedKeyList(dl):
    kl = list(dl.items())
    kl.sort()
    return kl

def tupleListToDict(a):
    b = {}
    for k, v in a:
        b[k] = b.get(k, [])+v
    return b

def main():
    gradeList = [('Zaphod', [33, 20]), ('Zaphod', [75, 48]), \
                 ('Slartibartfast', []), ('Trillian', [98, 88]), \
                 ('Trillian', [97, 77]), ('Slartibartfast', []), \
                 ('Marvin', [2000, 500]), ('Authur', [42, 20]), \
                 ('Authur', [64]), ('Trillian', [99]), \
                 ('Marvin', [450]), ('Marvin', [550]), \
                 ('Agrajag', []), ('Agrajag', []), ('Agrajag', [0]), \
                 ('Ford', [50]), ('Ford', [50]), ('Ford', [50])]

    print('\t', '\t', "Grade", '\t')
    print('\t', "Name", '\t', "Count", '\t', "Average")
    print("-----------------------------------------")

    dicList = tupleListToDict(gradeList)            
    dicList = getSortedKeyList(dicList)

    for k, v in dicList:
      try:
          print(k, len(v), '\t', sum(v)/len(v))
     except ZeroDivisionError as detail:
          print('Handling run-time error:', detail)
```

You can catch exception ZeroDivisionError by try and catch block;

Answer (score 0):

`Slartibartfast` has no grades, and thus `len(v)` is 0 when you get to his record.

Depending on what his "average" should be, you could modify the last loop to something like:

```
for k, v in dicList:
    print(k, len(v), '\t', sum(v)/len(v) if len(v)>0 else 'N/A')
```